# is it possible to get an xPages build number?

Tags: eclipse, compilation, lotus-notes, xpages, build-numbers

I do all development in a single application. when a new version is ready I create a template and give it a version number. this way I can store a history of all previous versions.

the development templates are used to push the new design to many applications via replace design.

Creating manual version number or template names is fine but I am looking for a more automatic way of finding out which build the different applications are inherited from

When I visit the different applications I would like to be able to see which build number each application are inherited from. is this possible?

A simple build time stamp could do, but is there a built in build number that can be used and that can be displayed on the xpage.

e.g Build 2012092712345

Update:
Thank you for all your answers, many good suggestions but it looks like all require manual work.

The best solution would be if there is a way to read (from ssjs) a timestamp from any file within the nsf that is always updated during a build. is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if something set automatically during the build process would help, because the database could be built on the production server. With plugins you can set version to e.g. 1.0.0.qualifier, and qualifier gets set when it's added to a feature / update site (and exported I think). There is a version in plugin.xml, but I'm not sure that will help, because the database is deployed as-is, not pulled into an update site or exported.

Answer (score 1):

In classic notes, there was a method to add a shared field with a special name to the application. Cannot remember the details, but have it somewhere on the disk.
Then you can see the build number in the design tab of the application properties. And you can of course display the value in your applikation as well. 
But you have to fill the item manually on each build. Or use teamstudio Buildmanager. This tool adds the value automatically.
And I also guess that you can write some code that changes the value whenever you create a new build.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a versioning system like CVS/SVN. This is possible since 8.5.3.

[Source control](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http://notesin9.com/index.php/2012/01/29/notesin9-041-xpages-designer-souce-control/&ei=QQpkULSoKI6SswbkoYDwAg&usg=AFQjCNFDAxl9qGpvU4LsSYrISxvCPRSssQ)

Comment: But how does this add a build number to the XPages app itself?

Comment: This won't add a build number to the xPage app itself but it could be a solution to the original question: "this way I can store a history of all previous versions.".

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are meaning. Your a pushing out design and want to check thru code what version each database has. I usually do this with a Build form. In this form I have computed fields with all the data I want to retrieve. Then I open the database with an agent create a document 
and set the form field to "BuildForm" and do a computewithform.
Now I can see all information about this database.

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote a rudimentary build system for "classic" Notes, and had the last part of the build pipeline create a form named `_BUILDID_`, and put the build id in the `$Comment` field.

The main reason to create a form instead of a shared field was that I could dynamically fetch the form using `NotesDatabase.Forms`, and open up the desired field.

I sure hope there are simpler solutions nowadays... :-)